# Can not exit for next in loops do loop untill

Tags: vba, excel

Can't exit `for..next` and run with  `do...loop until`. This code doesn't stop. I don't know what happens with code or my excel macro.

```
   Do
    For z = 1 To 7
        z = z
        i = i + 1
    Next z
  Loop Until i = 2
```

Comment: Each time the inner loop is executed, `i` is being incremented by 7.  So, if it started at `0`, when the `Loop Until i = 2` is first executed `i` would be 7.  The second time that statement is reached `i` will be 14.  It won't ever `=2`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you even loop to 7 in the `z` loop, all the time incrementing `i`,  if you want the Do-While to end when `i=2`? This whole thing just does not make sense.

Comment: i want to run for..next only 2 times that why i use do..loop until i = 2  . i use i to count sequences of for..next and limit it. Last time i already did it but now i don't know why i can't do it again. This code is the example like main code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a loop twice, change your code to either

```
i = 0
Do
    '...
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 2
```

or

```
For i = 1 To 2
    '...
Next
```